# How to delete/disfunction Restart option from LM20 shutdown menu?

Tags: linux-mint, services, reboot

I was able to look up only these files, they may or may not be related to my task:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-reboot.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target.wants
/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-reboot.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target.wants/plymouth-reboot.service
```

Current status:

[image: current shutdown menu]

The system is Linux Mint 20.2 - fresh and clean installation.

---

Summary: For an unknown reason one of my HW (Lenovo Z50-70) with the new SSD (Samsung 870 EVO, 2,5" - 250GB) is unable to perform *warm reboot*, and we are fine with this laptop being shut down and booted up again. Just want to be unable to accidentally hit Restart in the shutdown menu. We will also be satisfied if the Restart button does nothing or something harmless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get a proper answer so far, which is why I was experimenting a bit in a VM.

---

If I move this file away:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target
```

then the Restart button works as a Logout option, which is satisfactory, and I am going to implement this counter-measure.